# How to select the unique value of cell in a column

Tags: sql

When I perform "SELECT * FROM table" I got results like below:

```
1 UNID1 data1
2 UNDI2 data2
3 UNID3 data2
4 UNID4 data3
5 UNID5 data3
6 UNID6 data4
```

As you can see, there are dup records from column2 . So how could I just get result with the data which are not duplicate :

```
1 UNID1 data1
2 UNID6 data4
```

I don't beleive the DISTINCT option of SELECT command is the solution, as that return only different value not Unique value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, using an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.col1 <> t1.col1 AND t2.col2 = t1.col2);
```

[image]

### Demo

In plain English, this query says to fetch every record where there does *not* exist another record with a different `col1` ID value and the *same* `col2` value.

Comment: This is probably the most efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select max(col1) as col1, col2
from table t
group by col2
having count(distinct col1) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from (select a."col1",a."col2",a."col3",(select count(b."col3") from Table1 b 
where b."col3" like a."col3") count1
from Table1 a) where count1<2;
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/881ff/10